# Japanese Characters in Oracle BI Publisher

Tags: oracle10g, bi-publisher

We are using Oracle BI Publisher. We have a report in Japanese. The output of the report is in HTML and is getting displayed properly. When we send it as a mail using either schedule button or send button, the japanese text is not getting displayed properly. It is showing like > `å®šæœŸå•¥å ´æ¤œæŸ»ã¯ã€ä»Šå›žã®å•¥å >´æ¤œæŸ»ã®ç´„1å¹´å¾Œã«å®Ÿæ–½ã„ãŸã—ã¾ã™`

If someone has dealt with this earlier, kindly help. The encoding used is UTF-8(Unicode). It works fine for Spanish and Portuguese but not for Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'mojibake' string seems as if proper UTF-8 Japanese string is parsed as ISO-Latin.
I think that one of two following reasons is the cause.

1. Oracle BI Publisher does not set `Content-Type` properly.
2. Your or your customer's MUA(Mail User Agent) does not support `UTF-8` or Japanese.